# XML contents from ENTITY not loading

Tags: xml

I have an xml file that is using an ENTITY reference to pull xml content from a different file. I attempt to do this with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE message
[
<!ENTITY ref1 "<example>Some text</example>">   <!--Internal subset-->
<!ENTITY ref2 "Non-tag text">
<!ENTITY chap2 SYSTEM "ch02.xml">
]>

<!--End document prologue-->

<message type="SomeAtrribute">

&ref1;
&ref2;
&chap2;
... </message>
```

I've looked at other threads that detail this problem, and I have copied my code exactly to no avail.

The problem is the line `<!ENTITY chap2 SYSTEM "ch02.xml">` as the xml in that file, `ch02.xml`, is not being loaded in at the reference `&chap2;`. Whats wrong here?

Comment: Please identify what XML parser you are using, on what platform, and indicate how you are invoking it. Some environments disallow expansion of external entities for security reasons.

Comment: @Michael Kay I'm not using a parser I don't think, maybe I am. I'm very new to XML. Currently I am using Notepad++ to write this. I load the document with both Internet Explorer & Microsoft Edge, both to no avail. This is on Windows.

Comment: OK, so the XML parser you are using is the one in the browser. Unfortunately the XML parsers that come with browsers often do not support DTDs and external entities. I don't know about IE and Edge specifically, but I suspect that's what's happening.

Comment: @Michael Kay Bummer, thanks Michael. Do you by chance know another program I should use to remedy this?

Comment: I don't know of an XML parser that runs in the browser and does DTD validation and entity expansion. Which doesn't mean there isn't one.